# How I can reload all the opened pages of my website when I click a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, reload

**Im trying to reload all the opened pages when I change the $_SESSION variables**. But trying different approaches I dont now why it does not work. The reason of updating all the pages is because I have a functionality on my page for the admins that allows them works as a virtual user. So all the old session variables are updated and I store the old info. As this already work, **my problem now is how I can update this session variables in all my pages**. My approach is reloading all the pages but if its other chocice im am glad to hear it.
Thanks in advance

What I have in my last try for making all the things work is this:

I have on my event listener with jquery this

```
$('#virtual_user_data').on('click', function(){
  var user_type = $('#select_user_type').val();
  var user_id = $('#select_user').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'include_php/impersonate.php',
    async: false,
    data : {'user_type_id' : user_type, 'user_id' : user_id},
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data){
      window.postMessage({ type: "reload" }, "*");
      //console.log(message);
      
      if (user_type == 3)
        $(location).attr('href','home_provider.php');
      else if (user_type == 2)
        $(location).attr('href','home.php');
      
    }
  });
});
```

As I am sending a message to all the pages I create a script called reload.js with this:

```
$(window).on("message", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.data.type && event.originalEvent.data.type === "reload") {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

And finally I included this script to the pages I want to reload (only one for testing) and It does not work

Comment: `how I can update this session variables in all my pages`...if all the pages are open in tabs within the same browser window, they already share the same PHP session

Comment: Please clarify: Is this for a single user or multiple users?

Comment: @ADyson Yes the session is updated but if for example I store the user_name in the session and I print it, until I reload the pages this is not updated

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Is for only an user. This user is an admin a wants to go the virtual user part to acces as other user with other permissions

Comment: @RobertoGarcía that's how the web works. If you want something more dynamic, you'd need to either a) have all the pages frequently poll the server via AJAX to check for data changes - but this can quickly become inefficient, or b) employ something like Websockets or Server-Sent Events so that the server can send information out to the browser windows in real-time when something changes on the server. This is not a trivial thing to implement so you need to decide how important this functionality is for you, and/or whether your app could then get other benefits from having such an infrastructure

Comment: Instead of AJAX calls you could implement a [Shared Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) to update data on all open pages

Comment: There is the `BroadcastChannel` api [see here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_AP) that offers a really simple API that would allow all subscribed pages in your browser to be manipulated as you need

Comment: @Reyno How could implement with shared worker is the first time I heared of it. But in the url you posted is like sending messages also as I already have no?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thank you so much also It worked better that with the storage that commented one of the answers. I was having some problems with storage as some pages where reloading and other not but with this all pages reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try window storage event, It will emitted when your localstorage gets modified

```
addEventListener("storage", (event) => {
     // check your storage variable 
     // then reload your page here
});
```

Note: This is not work for same page, so this will call only when storage change by some other page

Thanks, let me know if this will not work

Comment: In this approach I will need first to create any storage variable or it’s not necessary?

Comment: Correct, you have to create one storage variable.

Comment: Thank you so much with storage it worked I can upvote because I just created the account but thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The approach you've taken to reload all the opened pages by using window.postMessage and an event listener seems correct. However, there might be a few reasons why it's not working as expected. Here are a few things you can check.

Ensure that you have included the jQuery library before using any jQuery functions.

Make sure that the reload.js script is included in all the pages where you want to reload the content.

As you are working with jquery remember to clear browser cache and watch console if you facing some js error.

Comment: Yes I have included this script in one of my pages for seeing if all works `<script src="include/js/reload.js?<?php echo $version_number; ?>"></script>` and i echo like a version number for not letting the browser cache my jquery. Trying this several time does not genereate any errrors in the console. but it does nor work

Comment: okay strange. What about storing SESSION in cookies and reading from there for all other pages?